# Some questions about `RANDOM(a, b)`

Tags: randomized-algorithms, randomness, pseudo-random-generators

This is a question from CLRS:

> Describe an implementation of the procedure RANDOM(a, b) that only makes calls
> to RANDOM(0, 1). What is the expected running time of your procedure, as a
> function of $a$ and $b$?

Here RANDOM(a, b) is a random number in the range $a, \ldots, b$.

Here is the answer:

```
RANDOM(a, b)
range = b - a
bits = floor(log(2, range)) + 1
result = 0
for i = 0 to bits - 1
    r = RANDOM(0, 1)
    result = result + r << i
if result > range
    return RANDOM(a, b)
else return a + result
```

Now I have some questions: Why has the book used the term randomized algorithm(expected running time which is for randomized algorithms)? Apparently, we call an algorithm randomized when there's some pseudorandom number generator in some part of it. So why has it called this algorithm itself randomized? As a result of `RANDOM(0, 1)`? what's the exact definition of a randomized algorithm? Is it possible that this algorithm doesn't terminate ?

Comment: Your solution assumes $b - a$ is a power of 2. Sez Wilkipedia: ["A randomized algorithm is an algorithm that employs a degree of randomness as part of its logic. ... In common practice, randomized algorithms are approximated using a pseudorandom number generator in place of a true source of random bits; such an implementation may deviate from the expected theoretical behavior."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm)

Comment: It is possible that this algorithm doesn't terminate although it terminates almost surely (i.e., with probability $1$). For example when $b-a$ is not a power of two and the generated number before the final `if` is always $2^{range}$. A randomized algorithm is an algorithm that has access to an oracle that can generate numbers according to some distribution. Usually this oracle can simulate a fair con flip, i.e., it return $0$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. All deterministic algorithms are trivially also randomized algorithms (but not vice-versa).

Comment: @vonbrand It should actually be `floor(log(2, range) + 1`. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Steven So any algorithm which contains a random number generator(whatever it is) is called randomized. Right? Should the numbers be equiprobable? Or it can be any distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that outputs a uniformly random number in the range $0,1,2,3$ given two uniformly random numbers in the range $0,1$:

```
RANDOM4(r0, r1):
    return r0 + 2*r1
```

In contrast, there is no algorithm that outputs a uniformly random number in the range $0,1,2$ given $N$ uniformly random numbers in the range $0,1$, for *any* value of $N$. The reason is that the probability that such an algorithm outputs $0$ is of the form $a/2^N$ for some integer $a$, and this cannot be equal to $1/3$.

However, given an infinite supply of uniformly random numbers in the range $0,1$, we can generate a uniformly random number in the range $0,1,2$ using a technique known as *rejection sampling*:

```
RANDOM3(r):
    for t in ℕ:
        a = r(2*t) + r(2*t+1)
        if a < 3:
            return a
```

Each iteration succeeds with probability $3/4$, and so the expected number of iterations is $4/3$. However, it is potentially unbounded.

Your algorithm also uses rejection sampling. The success probability is always more than $1/2$, so the expected number of iterations is less than $2$.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the expected number of calling `RANDOM(a,b)` is $\frac{2^{k}}{({2^{k} - 1})^{2}}$ where $k = \lfloor \log_{2}^{b - a} \rfloor + 1$? I calculated it this way: $$\sum_{i = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{i}{2^{ik}}$$

Comment: How do you get this formula?